# how to start python from php and pass python output back to php

Tags: python, php

I don't really know how to word this question but here it goes. I'm trying to start a scrape script from a php button. My scrape script would run, get all the info and send it back to my `index.php` to be posted. My scraping script works flawlessly and outputs all the information i need, but i have no idea where to even start to printing that information on php page.

Does that information need to be loaded dynamically because the script takes almost a minute to get all the information i need?
And if so, Where do i even start to do that?

Comment: Most browsers will timeout before a minute is up.  Is this something you could scrape once an hour in a cron script, and cache in a file for your PHP code to send back?

Comment: You can use `passthru` to run a command and send its output directly to the browser.  You can use `popen` to run a command, fetch its output as a string, and post-process it.